# HTML5 desktop application and C++ business logic

Tags: c++, html, websocket

I have a question related to HTML5 as a desktop application replacement.

At present time my company developed a WinCE application in C++ language with a GUI in C++, that receives and sends messages to the Business Logic layer via sockets (C++ Windows App).
We would like to port this SW on Linux but to realize a cross compilable SW.
The whole application run on a single embedded PC (both BL and GUI) .

About presentation layer we was investigating the HTML5 possible solution, however I have some doubts. 
In fact I read that some browsers supports the feature of web sockets, but it seems that this kind of sockets aren't generic TCP/UDP sockets, but are further specialized and their implementation is provided in server side classes, like Socket.IO (Java e node.js) and Jetty (Java).

So is there someone that can provide me some feedback about how/if it is possible to use HTML5 as presentation layer and send/receive updates from/to GUI via sockets to a application running on the same host machine as the web page?

I hope this question fulfill the requirements of the stackexchange "style" and rules, I made my best to be as clear as possible.
Best regards.
Giovanni Parodi

Comment: maybe you could add some tag to your question (maybe deleting the business-logic and presentation-layer tags) to attract the attention of the communities that follow those tags

Comment: Hi, can you suggest me some more attractive tags? I don't know what could better describe my problem. Thanks again, have a nice day

Comment: unfortunately no, because I'm not familiar with the tools you are using or are considering for use - except C++. It has many qualified followers, and your question is definitely related to C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing stops you from having your frontend and backend on same host talking via WebSocket over loopback.

I assume you are unwilling to port your backend to a different language, so you will need a C++ WebSocket implementation. I haven't followed what Microsoft provides in this area, but when using Boost/ASIO, I'd recommend to look at [WebSocket++](https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp).

Further, WebSocket is still relatively low-level (send message bidirectionally). So you might want something higher-level. You might want to look at [WAMP (The WebSocket Application Messaging Protocol)](http://wamp.ws/), which provides you with RPC and PubSub messaging patterns. Using this, you can plug/exchange your frontend (e.g. have a native Android) talking to same, unchanged backend - same for backend. Decoupling.

There are [clients](http://wamp-proto.org/implementations/#libraries) and [router(read: server)](http://wamp-proto.org/implementations/#routers) implementations for various languages.

Btw: WebSocket is supported by Chrome, Firefox and IE (beginning with version 10) -- and other browsers.

I'd need to know more about the specific side-conditions and requirements to give more hints ..

Disclosure: I am original author of Autobahn, WAMP and work for Tavendo.

Comment: Hi Oberset, first thanks a lot for your useful feedback.

You are right, I should save the business logic section that has been tested with different customers.
I need udp /tcp socket to send custom messages from gui to BL each time a user select a button, and messages to upgrade GUI depending on BL processes. Other kind of network messages are generated directly from BL, and doesn't need support of specific protocols from HTML5.
My new issue, is related to debugging tools, working with C++ in VS, I think debugging HTML5 will be much harder, do you have any hint about this topic?

Comment: Debugging HTML5/JavaScript compared to debugging C++ is order of magnitude easier. Chrome has that builtin: just google for Chrome developer tools. There is a complete debugger built into Chrome with breakpoints, single-stepping, bla bla bla. Recent versions of VS also have good support for JS ..

Comment: Great news, I'm sorry for my late reply, but I was not in my office today.

Comment: I'm sorry for my late reply, but I wasn't able to reply to your mail today. Thanks again for yor useful help.
So if I correclty understood, a good approach, instead of native C++ cross platform applications (i.e. QT Gui) could be implementing a HTML5 page and perform interaction between HTML5 GUI e C++ business logic through websocket++. I don't need to build application or web servers, but you suggest to build Boost on linux and use its websocket++ implementation. Can you confirm I'm right? Sorry for so many question, but I'm not an expert so I would like a new (last one) feedback

Comment: It is really difficult to give a thorough advice without knowing what you actually trying to achieve. Qt is cross-platform. HTML5 also. Both are IMHO sane UI techs. WebSocket++ is a WebSocket implementation built _on_ Boost/ASIO, not contained within. Boost/ASIO has it's own event loop. Qt also. If you run everything on 1 embedded PC, why split UI and BL? And if you don't split, you might as well use Qt/C++ doing a monolithic app (UI+BL in 1 executable). The whole question is too broad and a moving target. Sorry. I'm out.

Comment: First thanks again for your reply. We need to have two different executables in order, in the future, to be able to run the presentation layer on a PC connected via net to the embedded PC running BL. At present time we don't need this feature, but it could be critical quite soon. Thanks also for describing me the need for a event loop, that makes this solution as actractive as the QT one. We will think about this topics. Best regards